# Configuration Error when deploying active reports

Tags: asp.net, activereports

Mine is an active report using application which is working fine from local. When publishing this to server it showing configuration error with the Assessmbly in web.config. I've added the Licence.licx file to the root. App_licence.dll,ARVSPackage.dll to the correct folders. Even then its showing configuration error.

[Configuration Error http://www.delphinium.co.in/capture.jpg](http://www.delphinium.co.in/capture.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be realted to permissions, hence a suggestion for you would be to run the application on MediumTrust. Please refer to the following documentation link that will guide you through:
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arMediumTrustSupport.html

You may also refer to the following link wherein a similar issue has been discussed on the godaddy’s support page. This might be informative for you:
http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/request-to-add-arcacheitem-handler-to-iis/

Also, I am not sure if it would be possible to change trust level for shared hosting.

Regards,
Mohita